# Best practice for recording video calls

Tags: video-quality, video-capture

I’m a video producer isolated because of Covid19. I’m going to be spending a tonne of time recording guests over video calls.

So far I’ve been asking them to record audio locally, recording the google hangout, then resyncing the audio with Pluraleyes or manually, which is pretty time consuming.

Assuming that most of the people I’m recording are fairly non technical, are there any other better methods for getting the best out of a recorded video conference?

Are any of the machine learning frame rate and resolution enhancing services giving good results? Is there anything better than Pluraleyes for resyncing audio? I’m on a Mac with the adobe suite.

Comment: You could give the resolution enhancement a try. You can get a free trial of Topaz Gigapixel for a month and see how it goes. https://topazlabs.com/gigapixel-ai/ 
Also, Premiere has audio synching built-in these days.

Comment: the built in sync doesn't account for network delays and glitches in the video conf call..  Tried gigapixel but it didn't seem to improve the shot significantly.

Comment: The built-in sync can sync from the audio, which will cope with delays. I almost always shoot double-head with no slate or anything and it's all I ever use.

Comment: We used to mail a physical recording device and have the recipient ship it back for a podcast. We used an ipad mini for a while.  Never had trouble with people trying to steal it.  Of course, we didn't have sync issues because it was only audio, but if your guests were recording video and audio locally, sync wouldn't be an issue either.  All depends on your turnaround schedule.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Zoom, it has a pretty good recording feature which can record separate audio files for each participant in addition to the video in gallery view.  Obviously, already synced.

As far as quality, Zoom does have a video optimization option that improves the resolution at least.

Comment: Is there anything concrete you've read on whether their Cloud or Local recording is better quality?